# Formular una consulta a un archivo Json OPEN JSON con sub nodos

Tags: sql-server, json, jsonarray

Hola tengo la siguiente estructura de un json, pero al tener arreglos dentro de sus propiedades no logro explorar el objeto y tranformarlo a un query para despues insertarlo en base de datos.

```
{
"PersonalId": {
    "9120312AM": {
        "Identifier": "9120312AM",
        "AMXE": {
            "Date": "2007-06-18",
            "IdTest": 7355500000,
            "announceDt": "2007-06-18",
            "calcType": 460,
            "cdInstmtType": "UNKNOWN",
            "salIndustry": "WLES",
            "secType": "AMXE",
            "sectorSet": {
                "sectorRecord": [
                    {
                        "code": "WILE",
                        "level": 1,
                        "type": "TEST"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "TWIS",
                        "level": 1,
                        "type": "TEST"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "WLES",
                        "level": 0,
                        "type": "TEST"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Money": "MXN",
            "smSecType": "CORP",
            "structure": "SENIOR"
        }


      }
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

Necesito tranformalo a una consulta query, pero no logro más que lo siguiente, me podrian ayudar por favor con algunas ideas?

```
  DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

select @json = bulkcolumn from openrowset(bulk 'Path... Example.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS X

select  * from OPENJSON(@json, '$.PersonalId')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo envias como string y lo guardas en un `nvarchar(max)` usando `JSON.stringify`